# Can media queries change from ex. landscape to portrait view without refreshing browser?

Tags: responsive-design, media-queries, landscape-portrait

Hi there i have a question hope someone can help me. have tried to frind some topics about this but not anything that helps me.

I try to make media queries and i want them to change ex. from landscape view to portrait view on iPhone, iPad etc. without refreshing the browser? -And it still have to work on pc browser as well.

have tried

@media
   only screen and (min-width: 240px) and (max-width: 520px),
   only screen and (min-device-width: 240px) and (max-device-width: 520px) { ... }

Is that possible have tried alot of things and i'm standing still right now hopes that someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

media queries respond to change in orientation
they apply styles based on it and no they don't refresh your page

Here is a list of media-queries

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */
}
/**********
iPad 3
**********/
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
/* Styles */
}
/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen  and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen  and (min-width : 1824px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 4 ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
/* Styles */
}
```

Comment: Thanks but when i use min-device-width then the browser ignores the media queries

Comment: Using mobile phone or simulator for testing?

Comment: Using mobile phone but i use min-width in my queries and it works but i still want different rules for devices and browsers so the browser is not using the rules for devices. so can i solve this if i use min-device-width and max for devices, it will only be the devices there are using these rules. And so if i use min-width and max it will only be the browser that reads that? do you get the feeling where i'm going ? :-) - by the way all that with portrait and landscape view i solved it thanks :-)

Comment: i didnt get your question ..are you asking if you use `min-device-width` browser ignores this query? (if this is your q -NO).`min-width` or `min-device-width` both are read by the browser (irrespective ofthe device).min-width is a little different refer this answer-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26051087/about-responsive-sites-pixels-and-density/26053637#26053637

Comment: that was my question, but what is the diffenrence between them then?

Comment: `min-device-width` is the screen resolution` min-width``` is the css equivalent resolution.. My phone and my laptop both have 1080p screens.. Both have same device-width.. But css adds a layer on top of my mob screen to work with styling like font sizes (30px not easy if the css resolution is also 1080px on mobile phones ) this layer resolution is related to min-width property..which is about 640px..