# About responsive sites, pixels, and density

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design

I have coded a responsive website, in which I have CSS media queries to detect the screen size(pixels) of the device the user is navigating with.

Just standard medias. Example:

```
@media (max-width: 1199px){
  /*code*/
}
@media (max-width: 991px){
  /*code*/
}
@media (max-width: 767px){
 /*code*/
}
```

When I test my website with my mobile, which is a Samsung Galaxy S4 with 1920x1080 pixels my website shows me the mobile version, which is in this case the @media query with a max-width of 767px.

I understand that most things would be too small to read or be seen if my mobile respected exact measures like 12px font size.

So my question is, how do I control which version of my website is shown on high resolution devices, because pixels media queries aren't working in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@media (max-width: 1199px){
  /*code*/
}
```

The `max-width` property in the media query works a little different. It is not the resolution of the screen. It is equivalent css pixel.

Here are a couple of articles.

[A pixel identity crisis](http://alistapart.com/article/a-pixel-identity-crisis).

[A pixel is not a pixel is not a pixel](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/04/a_pixel_is_not.html).

[moz media query page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries).

If you want to target device resolution you should use

```
@media all and (max-device-width: 320px) {

}.
```

`max-device-width`:This property measures the device-width. If you write css using media query using this it will get a little complex (mobiles tabs and even desktops can have 1080p resolution screens). In order to target device resolutions you might have to look into properties like -`device-pixel-ratio` , `orientation` and `device-height` to give better control of layouts

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that you didn't include a [viewport meta-tag](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/09/combining_meta.html)

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

Comment: My index has this included 
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">`

Comment: The viewport meta tag does exactly what you are asking. If you combine a width media query with the meta viewport tag, your site will use the width that the device vendor considers optimal. Try removing the viewport meta tag and see the difference.

Comment: Hmm, nothing happens when I remove the meta tag. Is that normal?