# What's the exact screen size for Samsung galaxy S5?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have used BootStrap with media queries to make this site responsive. It's working fine on tablet and other devices. The only issue is with Samsung galaxy S5. Please have a look:
http://www.familylawbrampton.ca/

Comment: So you want us to...? with no code, no css, no html there isn't a pile much we can do

Comment: Have you included the Device width meta tag? Doubt it!

Comment: If you can't see the by pressing CTRL+U, you can't help me. I provided the URL.

Comment: So the answer is no?

Comment: I'm not sure Paulie_D, can you send me?

Comment: There's no viewport meta tag

Comment: Thanks Paulie and christina that was it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1080 x 1920, it's a 1080p screen, that's why you don't have it responsive i think, check the screen media in media queries to detect the mobile screen even if you have a 1080p display.

More informations about this phone can be found [here](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_s5-6033.php)

Comment: no that is not the reason..-he is not using `device-min-width` query he is using `min-width` queries .there is a difference between them http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26051087/about-responsive-sites-pixels-and-density/26053637#26053637